# How to enable "From <email address>" on Send an Email page

Tags: email, page-layout

I need to edit the Send an Email page layout. System admins see a different view than our sales team and I need them to see the same view. I do not see an email page layout. Where can this be done?

System Admin View:

[image]

Sales View:

[image]

We are missing the from field.

Comment: Oh boy,  can you try to rewrite your post? Add some screenshots if possible? Right now it does not look like a case I'd spend time solving =\

Comment: @kazoolsky I added screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need to configure your **Org wide Addresses** under **Email Administration** in **Setup**. From field in Send Email page displays the current Users Email address and along with that all other Org wide Email Addresses configured. If there were no Org wide Email Addresses configured for your profile, you will not see the From picklist in the Send Email page, as the default selection for From is the Current User's email.